# ReactiveUI: synchronize selected item of ListBox with TextBoxes

Tags: reactiveui

In an MVVM application with ReactiveUI:
I have a simple editor form for some entities, say Persons. On the left side I have a ListBox that shows all available persons. On the right side I have a form that shows the properies of the selected person. My in-code bindings look like this:

```
this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Persons, x => x.LBPersons.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.SelectedPerson, x => x.LBPersons.SelectedItem).DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Note that Person is a simple List and not an ObservableCollection. It gets loaded when the form is shown (this question is not about adding/deleting persons).

The bindings for the form controls that show the properties of the selected person look like this, I show only FirstName and LastName as an example:

```
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.SelectedPerson.FirstName, x => x.TBFirstName.Text, TBFirstName.Events().LostKeyboardFocus).DisposeWith(disposables);               

this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.SelectedPerson.LastName, x => x.TBLastName.Text, TBLastName.Events().LostKeyboardFocus).DisposeWith(disposables);
```

The ListBox items are built from combining first name and last name. What I would like to achieve, is automatically updating the ListBoxs' selected item while the user types into the form fields. (I guess I will have to get rid of the LostKeyboardFocus event selectors but that would still not result in automatic update).

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ReactiveUI documentation: [Choosing when to update the source](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/#choosing-when-to-update-the-source)

> By default, the source of a binding will be updated when the target changes, which is equivalent to setting UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged on a WPF binding.

You can verify this in [PropertyBinderImplementation.cs](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/f396c32159999686831c2801d4b7c4a538fd54a3/src/ReactiveUI/Bindings/Property/PropertyBinderImplementation.cs)

```
var signalObservable = signalViewUpdate != null
         ? signalViewUpdate.Select(_ => false)
         : view.WhenAnyDynamic(viewExpression, x => (TVProp)x.Value).Select(_ => false);
```

In order to propagate the changes, you should:

- Remove the event selector (fall back to default behavior)
- Verify you have notifying properties for `FirstName` and `LastName`
- You mentioned *"The ListBox items are built from combining first name and last name."*. Use an `ItemTemplate` to do that, as it will forward the changes.